# Undefined reference to `examplewindow::examplewindow()'

Tags: c++, g++

I got this error when compiling with g++ I searched online but I just can't find an answer for this. I tried to modify it but still, same error.

```
    /tmp/ccg3Y3r9.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `examplewindow::examplewindow()'
main.cc:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `examplewindow::~examplewindow()'
main.cc:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `examplewindow::~examplewindow()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my code

```
radio_buttons.h


#ifndef GTKMM_EXAMPLE_RADIOBUTTONS_H
#define GTKMM_EXAMPLE_RADIOBUTTONS_H

#include <gtkmm/box.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/radiobutton.h>
#include <gtkmm/separator.h>

class RadioButtons : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
  RadioButtons();
  virtual ~RadioButtons();

protected:
  //Signal handlers:
  void on_button_clicked();

  //Child widgets:
  Gtk::Box m_Box_Top, m_Box1, m_Box2;
  Gtk::RadioButton m_RadioButton1, m_RadioButton2, m_RadioButton3;
  Gtk::Separator m_Separator;
  Gtk::Button m_Button_Close;
};

#endif //GTKMM_EXAMPLE_RADIOBUTTONS_H
```

radiobuttons.cc

```
#include "radio_buttons.h"


RadioButtons::RadioButtons() :
  m_Box_Top(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL),
  m_Box1(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10),
  m_Box2(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10),
  m_RadioButton1("button1"),
  m_RadioButton2("button2"),
  m_RadioButton3("button3"),
  m_Button_Close("close")
{
  // Set title and border of the window
  set_title("radio buttons");
  set_border_width(0);

  // Put radio buttons 2 and 3 in the same group as 1:
  Gtk::RadioButton::Group group = m_RadioButton1.get_group();
  m_RadioButton2.set_group(group);
  m_RadioButton3.set_group(group);

  // Add outer box to the window (because the window
  // can only contain a single widget)
  add(m_Box_Top);

  //Put the inner boxes and the separator in the outer box:
  m_Box_Top.pack_start(m_Box1);
  m_Box_Top.pack_start(m_Separator);
  m_Box_Top.pack_start(m_Box2);

  // Set the inner boxes' borders
  m_Box2.set_border_width(10);
  m_Box1.set_border_width(10);

  // Put the radio buttons in Box1:
  m_Box1.pack_start(m_RadioButton1);
  m_Box1.pack_start(m_RadioButton2);
  m_Box1.pack_start(m_RadioButton3);

  // Set the second button active
  m_RadioButton2.set_active();

  // Put Close button in Box2:
  m_Box2.pack_start(m_Button_Close);

  // Make the button the default widget
  m_Button_Close.set_can_default();
  m_Button_Close.grab_default();

  // Connect the clicked signal of the button to
  // RadioButtons::on_button_clicked()
  m_Button_Close.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
              &RadioButtons::on_button_clicked) );

  // Show all children of the window
  show_all_children();
}

RadioButtons::~RadioButtons()
{
}

void RadioButtons::on_button_clicked()
{
  hide(); //to close the application.
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "radio_buttons.h"
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");

  RadioButtons buttons;

  //Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
  return app->run(buttons);
}
```

I searched online for answers but since I'm a beginner, I just can't make any sense out of the answers I found online. And here I am.

Comment: Is the code you are showing us your *actual* code? The code which causes the error? Because it doesn't mention anything about any `examplewindow` anywhere.

Comment: honestly, it sounds like you're not building the project you're showing here.